# How to add button to eclipse toolbar and connecting him to function xml extension Point

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hello I am trying to add button the main toolbar in elipse for my plug in.

I successfully add the button to the toolbar,But I fail in connecting this button to function that will open a property page.

This is my code in the xml:

```
    <plugin>
     <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Sample Category"
            id="FirstTextHoverTry.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Sample Command"
            categoryId="FirstTextHoverTry.commands.category"
            id="FirstTextHoverTry.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="FirstTextHoverTry.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="FirstTextHoverTry.SettingPage">
      </handler>
       <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
          <menuContribution
                locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
              <toolbar
                   id="opr.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
                <command
                      commandId="FirstTextHoverTry.Settings.SettingPage.execute"
                      icon="icons/sample.gif"
                      tooltip="Say hello world"
                      id="FirstTextHoverTry.Settings.execute">
                </command>
                </toolbar>
          </menuContribution>
       </extension>

</plugin>
```

The problem is probably in the commandId and id.

I have a "package" call Settings, that includes one class call SettingPage in here is my code of this class:
package Settings;

```
import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;

public class SettingPage extends AbstractHandler {

    public SettingPage() {
    }


    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "hi",
                "Need Somthing else probably");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `org.eclipse.ui.commands` and `org.eclipse.ui.handlers`

Comment: I don't have them, I just copied this extension point from the eclipse "Say,hello world" plugin which doesn't have those line but there it's just work ok. P.S I update the xml in the main qestion

Comment: Yes you do have them, you edit just shows them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point says your handler class is `FirstTextHoverTry.SettingPage` - so a class called `SettingPage` in the `FirstTextHoverTry` package, not the `Settings` package. So fix the package name.

Comment: Have a look at my edit is this what you ment for? if so, it still not wirking for me. If not, I probably not fully understand you right